# Every time I run a blending method on an image, the result is more and more saturated. How do I fix this?

Tags: java

I am using a method that takes an image and blends every pixel of it with a given color. My problem is that every time I run the method using the same image, the result is more and more saturated. Like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vuid.png)

I'm storing the image returned by the method as a different variable than the original one, and I'm passing through the original as the `image` parameter every time.

This is the blending method I'm using:

```
public static BufferedImage blendImage (BufferedImage image, Color blend) {
    BufferedImage newImage = image;

    for (int i = 0; i < image.getWidth(); i ++) for (int j = 0; j < image.getHeight(); j ++) {
        Color c1 = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j), true);
        Color c2 = blend;

        float r1 = ((float)c1.getRed()) / 255.0F;
        float g1 = ((float)c1.getGreen()) / 255.0F;
        float b1 = ((float)c1.getBlue()) / 255.0F;
        float a1 = ((float)c1.getAlpha()) / 255.0F;

        float r2 = ((float)c2.getRed()) / 255.0F;
        float g2 = ((float)c2.getGreen()) / 255.0F;
        float b2 = ((float)c2.getBlue()) / 255.0F;
        float a2 = ((float)c2.getAlpha()) / 255.0F;

        Color c3 = new Color(r1 * r2, g1 * g2, b1 * b2, a1 * a2);

        newImage.setRGB(i, j, c3.getRGB());
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

I'd like to know if there is some of fixing this or if there is a better way to blend images that anyone knows.

EDIT: It turns out that the method was changing the original image. I'm not sure how but it had something to do with the line `BufferedImage newImage = image;`. My solution was setting `newImage` to a new `BufferedImage` object, and making it the same width, height, and type as the `image` passed through. I don't know why the original image was being modified though.

Answer (score 1):

It's more accurate to say that your image is getting darker.

Here's what's happening. For each channel, you're normalizing the values of the image and the blend color to the range 0..1, and then multiplying them together. Since both numbers have a maximum of 1, the output value can never be larger than either of them and will probably be smaller. If you repeatedly blend with some color that's not pure white (255,255,255), the image will get progressively darker, even if the blend color is a bright one.

Maybe try averaging the channel values instead of multiplying them.

Or just draw a rectangle of the blend color over the whole image with 50% opacity.